# How can I make a counter when showing results from mySQL using php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to programming and got stuck in this infinite while loop when I am trying to show the results of the sql query in an order.

I have the entries ordered by date and time inside mySQL table.

When I display the results it does show up in the right order but  I wanted to have a counter and display that result in order 1,2,3..etc.

Right now I am showing the EventIDs in the html table straight from mySQL variable "EVENTID" from table 'eventtable'.

That displays the EVENTIDs which are of course not necessarily in order.

So I tried a while loop but it seems like I can not escape out from the first row of what mysqli_fetch_array() returns.

Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need this counter to be part of the actual query results, or just something you display to the user? user display is easy:

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = fetch_result_row_using_your_db_library()) {
   echo $counter;
   $counter++;
   ... do other stuff ..
}
```

Doing it at the DB level is a big uglier, involving DB variables and a self-incrementing counter in the query fields:

```
SET @row := 0;
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS currow,  * FROM .... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Just displaying to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark.
I put a while loop inside the other while loop of the fetch querry, that's why fell into the infinite while loop!
Doh me! Just like my username "smokedMeat"!

Cheers!

Comment: I did the self increment in the DB level with my primary key to suffice some other purpose but that's not what I was trying to to display to the user.

Thanks again Mark!

Comment: @Marc B, is there any reason to do not use 'echo $counter++' on a single line?

Comment: @vlad: keeping it simple... some people need to be spoon-fed answers, as opposed to being handed a package they need to unwrap themselves.